# Finding the sine graph equation given points

Tags: trigonometry

I'm having some difficulty finding the equation for this certain sine graph.

the given points are, ($\frac{\pi}{4}$,3),($\frac{\pi}{2}$,5),($\frac{3\pi}{4}$,3),($\pi$,1), and ($\frac{5\pi}{4}$,3).

I have gotten to the point of $2$sin($2$$x$-$\pi$)+$3$.

Any idea on the shift of this equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Try this function:

$$y=2\sin \left( 2x-\frac{\pi}{2} \right)+3$$

Comment: Yes I used it (attached a picture).